# How do I fix this strange exception : Exception in Tkinter callback

Tags: python, tkinter, exception, callback

I am working on a YouTube downloader project that takes a link and then puts the information about the video quality and sound quality of the link in the Combobox.

But when I try to put audio and video information in the Combobox, it gives this exception:

[image]

This is my code :

```
import tkinter

import tkinter.ttk

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import filedialog

from os import path

import pafy

from pafy import *

class Youtube():

    def __init__(self):
        self.label()
        self.entry()
        self.button()
        self.combobox()
        self.data=[]


    def label(self):

        Label(window, text='URL', font='bold').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=100)
        Label(window, text='Destination', font='bold').grid(row=2, column=0, padx=100)
        Label(window, text='File Name', font='bold').grid(row=4, column=0, padx=100)

        Label(window, text='Video Quality', font='bold').grid(row=6, column=0, pady=20)
        Label(window, text='Audio Quality', font='bold').grid(row=7, column=0, pady=5)

        Label(window, text='Download Type', font='bold').grid(row=8, column=0, pady=15)
        Label(window, text='Combine AV', font='bold').grid(row=8, column=1)

    def entry(self):
        global een
        global en
        en=Entry(window, width=35, borderwidth=10)
        en.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=100, pady=5)
        een=Entry(window, width=35, borderwidth=10)
        een.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=100, pady=5)
        Entry(window, width=35, borderwidth=10).grid(row=5, column=0, padx=100, pady=5)

    def button(self):
        Button(window, text='i', height=1, width=3, command=self.information).grid(row=1, column=1)
        Button(window, text='d', height=1, width=3, command=self.destination).grid(row=3, column=1)

        Button(window, text='Download', font='bold').grid(row=12, column=0, padx=150, pady=10, columnspan=3)


    def combobox(self):
        tkinter.ttk.Combobox(window,  width=15).grid(row=6, column=1)
        tkinter.ttk.Combobox(window,  width=15).grid(row=7, column=1, pady=5)

        tkinter.ttk.Combobox(window, values=['Audio only', 'Vido only', 'Audio and vido'],
                             width=15).grid(row=9, column=0)
        tkinter.ttk.Combobox(window, values=['Yes', 'No'], width=15).grid(row=9, column=1, pady=20)

        tkinter.ttk.Progressbar(window, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300,
                                mode='determinate').grid(row=11, column=0, padx=200, pady=10, columnspan=3)


    def destination(self):
        path = str(filedialog.askdirectory())
        een.insert(tkinter.END, path)



    def information(self):
       global link
       link = en.get()
       self.video()
       self.audio()


    def video(self):
        video_quality_list = []
        self.data = pafy.new(link)
        video_streams = self.data.videostreams
        for video_quality in video_streams:
            video_quality_list.append(video_quality)
        tkinter.ttk.Combobox(window, values=video_quality_list, width=15).grid(row=6, column=1, pady=5)


    def audio(self):
        audio_quality_list = []
        self.data = pafy.new(link)
        audio_streams = self.data.audiostreams
        for audio_quality in audio_streams:
            audio_quality_list.append(audio_quality)
        tkinter.ttk.Combobox(window, values=audio_quality_list, width=15).grid(row=7, column=1)

window = Tk()

mywin = Youtube()

window.title('Youtube Downloader')

window.geometry("700x600+10+10")

window.mainloop()
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you test the `pafy` package?

Comment: I think it's not updated with new YouTube features. As it's latest version released at 2019.

Comment: I found the answer to my question here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLWEMrcqsjs&t=211s